# Whether one of the elements of an array or a hash is nil

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there any method that tells that one of the elements of an array or a hash is nil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an array

```
array = [1, 2, 'a']
array.any?(&:nil?)
#=> false
```

For a hash, I guess you are talking about nil values.

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => nil}
hash.value?(nil)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `any?` method: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

For example:`arr.any? { |x| x.nil? }`

Answer (score 1):

As oldergod and strmstn have pointed out you should use any, and in the condition inside block you can verify whether an element is a `nil` or its class is `Hash`

```
[1,2,nil].any? {|x| x.class == Hash or x.nil? } # => true

[1,2,{}].any?  {|x| x.class == Hash or x.nil? } # => true
```